# Construct a openssl service with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256

Tags: c, mongoose, openssl

I am building a HTTPS service with Mongoose using using OPENSSL (openssl-1.0.2) on an embedded Linux.  I tried it first using the following cipher list "AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384", and it works fine.  However, when I try to use only "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", the compilation still works, but when attempting actual HTTPS connection between server and client (Chrome on Windows 10), the connection always failed at handshake.

Here's the openssl supported cipher list:

```
# openssl ciphers | sed 's/:/\n/g'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
...
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
...

#
```

According to the packet capture between server and client, the client does support ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, so logically the handshake should work.  The certificate is signed using RSA Key.

Here's my code for setting up SSL connection.

```
const char *pem = ctx->config[SSL_CERTIFICATE];
const char *chain = ctx->config[SSL_CHAIN_FILE];
if (!load_dll(ctx, SSL_LIB, ssl_sw) || !load_dll(ctx, CRYPTO_LIB, crypto_sw))
    return 0;
  
// Initialize SSL crap
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();

**if ((CTX = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_server_method())) == NULL)
    printf("SSL_CTX_new error: %s", ssl_error());**


/** Set cipher list */
//char cipher[128]="AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384";
char cipher[128]="ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256";
if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(CTX, cipher) <= 0) {
    printf("Failed setting the cipher list.\n");
    return 0;
}

if (CTX != NULL && SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(CTX, pem, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) == 0) {
    printf("%s: cannot open %s: %s", __func__, pem, ssl_error());
    return 0;
}else if (CTX != NULL && SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(CTX, pem, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) == 0) {
    printf("%s: cannot open %s: %s", NULL, pem, ssl_error());
    return 0;
}

if (CTX != NULL && chain != NULL && SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(CTX, chain) == 0) {
    printf("%s: cannot open %s: %s", NULL, chain, ssl_error());
    return 0;
}
```

All I did are,

1. Changing the method from **SSLv23_server_method()** to **TLSv1_2_server_method()**,
2. Changing the cipher list from **"AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384"** to **"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"**

Any help would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: To use ECDHE suites in 1.0.x you must call either (classic but clumsy) `SSL_[CTX_]set_tmp_ecdh[_callback]` or (better, new in 1.0.2) `SSL_[CTX_]set_ecdh_auto(nonzero)`. (Set the SSL_CTX before SSL_new or the SSL after.) (In 1.1.x it automatically uses the equivalent of ecdh_auto(true).)

Comment: BTW it's not the type of signature on the certificate that matters but the type of key IN the certificate, and the (must be matching) privatekey. Often these are the same, but they don't have to be. Also the KeyUsage matters, as do some other cert attributes/extensions.

Comment: It works, thank you.  All I did is adding SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(CTX, 0);

Comment: May I ask one additional question, I am trying to support both RSA and DSA at the same time, I tried to concatenate one DSA key/certificate into RSA key/certificate, but still only RSA is detected, is there other ways to do it?